# How to call main thread function from the Service on android?

Tags: android, static, cursor

I have Main class and it contains function `isSyncAllowed`. I start another service. How to call function `isSyncAllowed` from this service?
It says:

> Cannot make a static reference to the
>   non-static method
>   isSyncAllowed(Boolean) from the type
>   Main

If I change type of that function to `static` and pass `context`, I come to the problem that startManagingCursor can not be static.

How can I fix it?

Upd. Here is the code of **SyncService**:

```
public class SyncService extends BroadcastReceiver {
...
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    Boolean isDownloadAllowed = Kinobaza.isSyncAllowed(true);
    }
```

and here is the code of **Main**:

```
public class Kinobaza extends ListActivity {
    ...
    public static Boolean isSyncAllowed(Boolean showToasts) {
        ...
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor); // here is the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Without code, and with us having to guess as to what `Main` is, you are unlikely to get much help.

Comment: The code is quite long. Let me re-phrase my question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing `Main.isSyncAllowed(...)` instead of `main.isSyncAllowed(...)`, where `main` is an object of class `Main`.

If you are inside an instance method of `Main`, then you can simply do `isSyncAllowed(...)`.

**Edit** - now that I see your code, you should probably pass `isSyncAllowed` via the `Intent` you give to the service. When you start the service:

```
Intent intent = /* however you were constructing your intent */
boolean syncAllowed = /* calculate syncAllowed by calling your existing method */
intent.putExtra("syncAllowed", syncAllowed);
    ...
```

and then in your service you can retrieve it:

```
boolean syncAllowed = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("syncAllowed", true);
```

Your service shouldn't need to call instance methods on your activities.

Comment: if I keep isSyncAllowed as non-static and then create object like `Main main = new Main()`, then my application crashes. Main is the main class of application.